# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 Java 8

Tags: java-8

```
ABC abc = eMsg.getAbcCont().stream()
                        .filter(cnt -> (option.geiID().equals(cnt.getId()) && option.getIdVersion() == cnt.getIdVersion()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0); 
delEmsg.getAbcCont().remove(abc);
```

Above code is giving me en exception as

> ```
> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
> at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
> at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
> ```

`getAbcCont` method will return the List of ABC objects.Currently my eMsg contains two object with the getAbcCont. When control reach to the `.collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0);` its giving the above mentioned exception. Any help suggestion must be appricaited.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understand Arraylist IndexOutOfBoundsException in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21570318/understand-arraylist-indexoutofboundsexception-in-android)

Comment: The answer is worth a read in the link above and shall drive you better understand instead just making a quick fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means that the result after the filter is zero elements, so you cannot do `get(0)`.

A quick solution for this would be to first get the list of elements back, and then check if there is atleast one element.

```
List<ABC> list = ABC abc = eMsg.getAbcCont().stream()
                        .filter(cnt -> (option.geiID().equals(cnt.getId()) && option.getIdVersion() == cnt.getIdVersion()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());

if(list.size() > 0){
 ABC abc = list.get(0);
}
```

Obviously there is a shorter way also using lambdas such as:

```
ABC abc = eMsg.getAbcCont().stream()
                        .filter(cnt -> (option.geiID().equals(cnt.getId()) && option.getIdVersion() == cnt.getIdVersion()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()).findFirst().orElse(null)
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26126636/1688441

But as User  nullpointer , you might need to check if an element is found before you try to call `remove()` using object abc. I suspect trying to remove null from a collection might not do anything, but you could check to be sure!

```
if(abc != null){
 delEmsg.getAbcCont().remove(abc);
}
```

Comment: I think you missed `delEmsg.getAbcCont().remove(abc);` in the question...`orElse(null)` can result into a possible NPE here.

Answer (score 0):

You should do !list.isEmpty() rather than list.size() as per sonar